# Upgrade Rasp Pi 4 with ubuntu server from 21.04 to 22.04

Tags: raspberrypi

If I try to upgrade my Rasp Pi 4 running **ubuntu server 21.04** I receive a warning that the upgrade to 21.10 is not supported.

I would upgrade to **22.04** which I know supports Rasp Pi 4.
It's possible without reinstalling it?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute


ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ sudo do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

New release '21.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife


= Welcome to Ubuntu 21.10 'Impish Indri' =

The Ubuntu team is proud to announce Ubuntu 21.10 'Impish Indri'.
```

Tnx

Comment: You need to do such release upgrades while the current release it's still supported, not the case with 21.04. There's a method for desktops (x86_64) by pointing the repositories information to the now archived ones but I'm not sure if it can be done for ARM (arm64)

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 has reached the end of life. It is not maintained and updated anymore. This means it may be easier to do a fresh and clean install of the version 22.04.

Comment: hmmm... ok. I have 2 docker containers on this RaspPi4. So now I will stop docker, backup the entire volume, and then install a new OS on the new SD... if all is ok, I will copy the volume and setting